# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a regression using the following dataframe `dfMyRoll` the head of the dataframe looks like:

```
                SCORE  SCORE_LAG
date                           
2007-10-29 -0.031551        NaN
2007-10-30  0.000100  -0.031551
2007-10-31  0.000100   0.000100
2007-11-01  0.000100   0.000100
2007-11-02  0.000100   0.000100
```

The code that I am using is :

```
import glob
import pandas as pd 
import os.path
import scipy
from scipy.stats import linregress

def main():
        
    dataPath = "C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/data/Roll"
    roll = 4
    1ID = "BBG.XNGS.AAPL.S"
    2ID = "BBG.XNGS.AMAT.S"
    print(1ID,1ID)
    cointergration = getCointergration(dataPath,1ID,2ID,roll)
    
    return

def getCointergration(dataPath,1ID,2ID,roll):
   
    for myRoll in range((roll-4),roll,1):
        path = dataPath+str(myRoll)+'/'
        filename='PairData_'+1ID+'_'+2ID+'.csv'
        
        for fname in glob.iglob(path+filename):
            
            dfMyRoll = pd.read_csv(fname, header=0, usecols=[0,31],parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True,index_col=[0], names=['date', 'SCORE'])
            dfMyRoll['SCORE_LAG'] = dfMyRoll['SCORE'].shift(1)
            print('cointergration',dfMyRoll.head())
         
            X = dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE']
            
            Y = dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE_LAG']
          slope,intercept,_,_,stderr=linregress(dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE'],dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE_LAG'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    print ("CointergrationTest...19/05/17")

    try:
        
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        
        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

I get the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.  I have looked at previous posts on this subject and tried adding iloc to the X and Y time series in the following way:

```
        X = dfMyRoll.iloc[1:,'SCORE']
        
        Y = dfMyRoll.iloc[1:,'SCORE_LAG']
```

but unfortunately I can't seem to find a solution.  Please see below for a stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-431422978139>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/scripts/cointergrationTest.py', wdir='C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/scripts')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/scripts/cointergrationTest.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/scripts/cointergrationTest.py", line 23, in main
    cointergration = getCointergration(dataPath,1ID,2ID,roll)

  File "C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/scripts/cointergrationTest.py", line 42, in getCointergration
    X = dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE']

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2059, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1384, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Comment: That's not the correct indexing syntax. `dfMyRoll[1:,'SCORE']`  should actually be `dfMyRoll.loc[1:,'SCORE']` assuming you have an integer range index.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use loc rather than iloc:

```
X = dfMyRoll.loc[1:,'SCORE']

Y = dfMyRoll.loc[1:,'SCORE_LAG']
```

iloc is read as "integer location", and only accepts integer position. loc is somewhat more forgiving and allows both (you can also use `ix`).

Comment: Thanks, I have a datetime index <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> which means I get a new error: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [1] of <class 'int'>.  Could you let me know how to iloc with datetime please?

Comment: @Stacey please try with ix, looks like this behavior might have changed.... hmmm.

Comment: @Stacey i.e. `dfMyRoll.ix[1:,'SCORE']`